Fatal error: Storage daemon didn't accept Device "FileStorage" command
i'm checking through our backups and i'm seeing some backups (full and incremental aswell) are failing with this error.

Fatal error:
Storage daemon didn't accept Device "FileStorage" command.

i checked on the storage servers and the permissions on the BAREOS folder seem ok.
what could cause this issue?
